# Jmeter Regular expression with quotes

Tags: regex, jmeter

In my Jmeter testing, I have a HTTP request which gives me Response data:

```
{"sessionid":"2da1c436-5ecf-4ce3-b908-705d9b3ed2a0","status":"successful"}
```

I have added a Regular Expression Extractor with following info:

```
Apply to: Main Sample only
Field to Check: Body

Reference Name: data1
Regular expression: "status":”(.+?)”
Template: $1$
Match No: 0
Default  Value: REGEX_FAILED
```

However I never get `${data1}` equal to successful (even though it is). It always gives me `REGEX_FAILED`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I see some odd quotes in your pattern:

```
Regular expression: "status":”(.+?)”
```

shouldn't that be:

```
Regular expression: "status":"(.+?)"
```

?

Comment: If @Bart Kiers has solved your problem, please upvote his answer and mark it as correct.